# Old (sklearn 0.17) GMM, DPGM, VBGMM vs new (sklearn 0.18) GaussianMixture and BayesianGaussianMixture

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, gaussian, unsupervised-learning

In previous scikit-learn version (0.1.17) I used the following code to automatically determine best Gaussian mixture models and optimize hyperparameters (alpha, covariance type, bic) for unsupervised clustering.

```
# Gaussian Mixture Model 
try:       
    # Determine the most suitable covariance_type
    lowest_bic = np.infty
    bic = []
    cv_types = ['spherical', 'tied', 'diag', 'full']
    for cv_type in cv_types:
        # Fit a mixture of Gaussians with EM
        gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=NUMBER_OF_CLUSTERS, covariance_type=cv_type)
        gmm.fit(transformed_features)
        bic.append(gmm.bic(transformed_features))
        if bic[-1] < lowest_bic:
            lowest_bic = bic[-1]
            best_gmm = gmm
            best_covariance_type = cv_type
    gmm = best_gmm
except Exception, e:       
    print 'Error with GMM estimator. Error: %s' % e 

# Dirichlet Process Gaussian Mixture Model  
try:
    # Determine the most suitable alpha parameter
    alpha = 2/math.log(len(transformed_features))     
    # Determine the most suitable covariance_type
    lowest_bic = np.infty
    bic = []
    cv_types = ['spherical', 'tied', 'diag', 'full']
    for cv_type in cv_types:
        # Fit a mixture of Gaussians with EM
        dpgmm = mixture.DPGMM(n_components=NUMBER_OF_CLUSTERS, covariance_type=cv_type, alpha = alpha)
        dpgmm.fit(transformed_features)
        bic.append(dpgmm.bic(transformed_features))
        if bic[-1] < lowest_bic:
            lowest_bic = bic[-1]
            best_dpgmm = dpgmm
            best_covariance_type = cv_type        
    dpgmm = best_dpgmm                
except Exception, e:       
    print 'Error with DPGMM estimator. Error: %s' % e    

# Variational Inference for Gaussian Mixture Model   
try: 
    # Determine the most suitable alpha parameter 
    alpha = 2/math.log(len(transformed_features))  
    # Determine the most suitable covariance_type
    lowest_bic = np.infty
    bic = []
    cv_types = ['spherical', 'tied', 'diag', 'full']
    for cv_type in cv_types:
        # Fit a mixture of Gaussians with EM
        vbgmm = mixture.VBGMM(n_components=NUMBER_OF_CLUSTERS, covariance_type=cv_type, alpha = alpha)
        vbgmm.fit(transformed_features)
        bic.append(vbgmm.bic(transformed_features))
        if bic[-1] < lowest_bic:
            lowest_bic = bic[-1]
            best_vbgmm = vbgmm
            best_covariance_type = cv_type
    vbgmm = best_vbgmm     
except Exception, e:       
    print 'Error with VBGMM estimator. Error: %s' % e
```

How to accomplish same or similar behaviour with new Gaussian Mixture/ Bayesian GAussian Mixture models introduced in scikit-learn 0.1.18?

According to scikit-learn documents, there is no "alpha" parameter anymore, but there is "weight_concentration_prior" parameter instead. Are these the same or not?
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture

> weight_concentration_prior : float | None, optional.
>       The dirichlet concentration of each component on the weight distribution (Dirichlet). The higher concentration puts more mass in
>   the center and will lead to more components being active, while a
>   lower concentration parameter will lead to more mass at the edge of
>   the mixture weights simplex. The value of the parameter must be
>   greater than 0. If it is None, it’s set to 1. / n_components.

http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.VBGMM.html

> alpha: float, default 1 :
>       Real number representing the concentration parameter of the dirichlet distribution. Intuitively, the higher the value of alpha the
>   more likely the variational mixture of Gaussians model will use all
>   components it can.

If those two parameters (alpha and weight_concentration_prior) are the same, does it mean that the formula alpha = 2/math.log(len(transformed_features)) still aplies for the weight_concentration_prior = 2/math.log(len(transformed_features))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BIC score is still available for the classical / EM implementation of GMMs as implemented in the GaussianMixture class.

The BayesianGaussianMixture class can automatically tune the number of effective components (n_components should just be big enough) for a given value of `alpha`.

You can also use standard cross validation on the loglikelihood (using the `score` method of the model).

Comment: It seems that there is no "alpha" parameter anymore. Instead, there is "weight_concentration_prior" parameter. I'm not sure whether these two are actually the same or not?

Comment: Also, it seems that while in GaussianMixture class there is BIC and AIC still present (as @ogrisel pointed out), there is no BIC and AIC in BayessianGaussianMixture. Why?

Comment: The new weight_concentration_prior is the equivalent of the old alpha besides the fact that the deprecated implementation had several bugs, the new implementation seems correct has far as I know.

Comment: I think the fact that the old VBGMM had a bic method was not intentional VBGMM was a subclass of GMM while BayesianGaussianMixture is not a direct subclass of GaussianMixture but they share a common base class. I am not sure if the implementation of the BIC score is correct for BayesianGaussianMixture. If it is we could move the bic method implementation to the base class.

Comment: is parameter "weight_concentration_prior" the same as previous parameter "alpha"?

Comment: Yes as I said above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931922/old-sklearn-0-1-17-vs-new-sklearn-0-1-18-gmm-dpgm-vbgmm/39935265?noredirect=1#comment67174231_39935265

Comment: To be more precise weight_concentration_prior is the same as alpha for VBGMM when weight_concentration_prior_type is set to "dirichlet_distribution" instead of "dirichlet_process".

Comment: Thanks you for answer.